# Change search query in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, location

I have a search field which allows the user to search for places and postcodes. When the user inputs the search value, I have two hidden input fields which populate the latitude and longitude based on user selection.

I want to run a query which searches for posts with the hidden input values - `latitude` and `longitude` and ***not*** what the user types in.

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="">
<div class="search">
<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="search-input" class="s" placeholder="Enter your Location or Postcode" />
<input type="hidden" value="profile" name="post_type" id="post_type" />
<input type="hidden" value="country" name="taxonomy" />
<input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="latitude" />
<input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="longitude"/>
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" class="submit btn" />
</form>
```

**How can I replace the search query completely with another query searching for posts based on the user selection of latitude and longitude?**

This is the SQL query which I want to replace the main query with:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts. * 
FROM wp_posts
WHERE 1 =1
AND wp_posts.ID
IN (

SELECT post_id
FROM lat_lng_post
WHERE ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( - 27.922459 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lng ) - RADIANS( 153.334793 ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( - 27.922459 ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( lat ) ) ) ) <=125
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I have a function ready but I'm not sure which Wordpress hook should I use to change the search query to another one **[without modifying the search template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/190275/447)**:

```
function custom_search() 
{

    global $wpdb;

    if (is_search())
    $latitude = filter_input( INPUT_GET, "latitude", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $longitude = filter_input( INPUT_GET, "longitude", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $radius = 125;

    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts. * 
                FROM wp_posts
                WHERE 1 = 1
                AND $wpdb->posts.ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM lat_lng_post WHERE 
                 ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(%f) ) 
                                * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
                                * cos( radians( lng ) 
                                - radians(%f) ) 
                                + sin( radians(%f) ) 
                                * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) <= %s)";

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql, $latitude, $longitude, $latitude, $radius);

    //$wpdb->show_errors();
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    //$wpdb->print_error();       


    return $results;

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you hook into posts_clauses and use the $pieces object to alter the query? (I would add this as a comment but don't have the reputation)

```
add_filter('posts_clauses', function($pieces, $obj) {
    print_r($pieces);
});
```

Hm - this might still not be enough. post_clauses $pieces object returns:

```
Array (
    [where] =>  AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%test%') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%test%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%test%')))  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
    [groupby] => 
    [join] => 
    [orderby] => wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%test%' DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC
    [distinct] => 
    [fields] => wp_posts.*
    [limits] => LIMIT 0, 10
)
```

Comment: Can you please give an example? As I want to alter the query completely and not just parts of it.

Comment: Ah, sorry - post_clausules would be a better one. See updated answer.